# Nosetests error in code where exception is manually raised

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program to practice but its test code keeps on failing. Here is the main code:

```
class Bank(object):

    def __init__(self, name, deposit=0, withdraw=0, balance=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.withdraw = withdraw
        self.balance = balance

    def deposited(self):
        self.balance += self.deposit
        return self.balance

    def withdrawn(self):
        if self.balance < self.withdraw:
            raise ValueError("INSUFFICIENT BALANCE!")
        else:
            self.balance -= self.withdraw
            return self.balance
```

This is its test code:

```
from nose.tools import *
from bank.account import Bank

def test_account():
     Maria = Bank('Maria', None, None)
     assert_equal(Maria.name, 'Maria')
`   `assert_equal(Maria.balance, 0.0)
     assert_equal(Maria.deposit, None)
     assert_equal(Maria.withdraw, None)

    Sam = Bank('Sam', 10, 1)
    assert_equal(Sam.name, 'Sam')
    assert_equal(Sam.balance, 0.0)
    assert_equal(Sam.deposit, 10)
    assert_equal(Sam.withdraw, 1)

def test_deposit():
    Rotschild = Bank('Rotschild', 100, 0)
    Rotschild.deposited()
    assert_equal(Rotschild.balance, 100)

def test_withdaw():
    Morgan = Bank('Morgan', 100, 50)
    Morgan.deposited()
    Morgan.withdrawn()
    assert_equal(Morgan.balance, 50)

    Bill = Bank('Bill', 5, 10)
    Bill.deposited()
    assert_raises(ValueError, Bill.withdrawn())
```

Upon running nosetests, it always shows Failed(error=1), i cannot figure out if it is a problem with the syntax or what.
I want the test to raise the exception when the account balance is less than the amount withdrawn.

Comment: Are you sure you formatted your code properly? There are some indentation issues in the `test_account` function.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum yes i am sure, i made an error while copying the code.

Comment: Can you update it to the correct code?